# Derivative of Var($\alpha X + (1 - \alpha)Y$) w.r.t. $\alpha$?

Tags: derivatives, variance

It's supposed to result as

$
  2\alpha \sigma_x^2 - 2\sigma_Y^2 + 2\alpha\sigma_Y^2 + 2\sigma_{XY}-4\alpha\sigma_{XY}
$

But I don't remember the rules of Var() algebra.

Comment: Hm... I just had this as a homework question - except we assumed independence.

Comment: If you assume independence then the covariances disappear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variances have some unusual rules.  A sort of "quasi" linear operator, if you will.  Its not exactly linear over sums, and it isnt exactly linear over scalar multiples. But close. Technically it's called a *quadratic form*.

With regards to scalar multiples, $\mathrm{Var}(sX) = s^2 \mathrm{Var}(X)$, the scalar gets pulled out but it gets squared.

A similar thing happens with covariances, since variances are simply covariances of distributions with themselves: $\mathrm{Var}(X) = \mathrm{Cov}(X,X)$.  We can observe this consistent property with scalar factors: $\mathrm{Cov}(sX, tY) = st \mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)$.  Covariances are called *bilinear forms*, because they are independently linear in each of their arguments.  Thus, $\mathrm{Var}(sX) = \mathrm{Cov}(sX,sX)= s^2\mathrm{Cov}(X,X)= s^2\mathrm{Var}(X)$.

With regard to sums, we would like it if $\mathrm{Var}(X+Y) = \mathrm{Var}(X)+\mathrm{Var}(Y)$ but this is only true for uncorrelated/independent distributions.  In the general case, however, $\mathrm{Var}(X+Y) = \mathrm{Var}(X) + \mathrm{Var}(Y) + 2\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)$.  Covariance is naturally zero if and only if the distributions are uncorrelated.

Thus, for your expression, we have:
$$\mathrm{Var}(\alpha X + (1-\alpha)Y) =\\ \mathrm{Var}(\alpha X) + \mathrm{Var}((1-\alpha)Y) +2\mathrm{Cov}(\alpha X,(1-\alpha)Y) =\\ \alpha^2 \mathrm{Var}(X) + (1-\alpha)^2\mathrm{Var}(Y) + 2\alpha(1-\alpha)\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)$$

From there you differentiate with respect to $\alpha$.  The traditional product and chain rules apply, and recognizing that with respect to $\alpha$, everything else is a relative constant, to be treated as such in the rules of calculus.
$$\frac{d}{d\alpha}\left[ \alpha^2 \mathrm{Var}(X) + (1-\alpha)^2\mathrm{Var}(Y)  + 2\alpha(1-\alpha)\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)\right] = \\  2\alpha \mathrm{Var}(X) - 2(1-\alpha)\mathrm{Var}(Y)  + 2(1-\alpha)\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) - 2\alpha\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) = \\  2\alpha \mathrm{Var}(X) -2\mathrm{Var}(Y) + 2\alpha\mathrm{Var}(Y) + 2\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) - 4\alpha\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)$$

Variances and covariances can alternatively be written:
$$2\alpha \sigma_X^2 -2\sigma_Y^2 + 2\alpha\sigma^2_Y + 2\sigma_{X,Y} - 4\alpha\sigma_{X,Y}$$

$\blacksquare$

So yeah, the expression does look right.

---

On a side note. And thanks be to a commentor for reminding me. I thought this was superfluous, but in case youre interested...

These are some useful properties too.

Covariances are called *bilinear forms* because they are linear in each of its arguments. Linear in the first argument:

1. $\mathrm{Cov}(sX, Y) =s\mathrm{Cov}(X, Y)$,
2. $\mathrm{Cov}(X+Z, Y) =\mathrm{Cov}(X, Y)+\mathrm{Cov}(Z, Y)$

Linear in the second argument:

3. $\mathrm{Cov}(X, tY) =t\mathrm{Cov}(X, Y)$,
4. $\mathrm{Cov}(X, Y+Z) =\mathrm{Cov}(X, Y)+\mathrm{Cov}(X, Z)$

Hence "bilinear". Clearly we get $\mathrm{Cov}(sX, tY) = st\mathrm{Cov}(X, Y)$ from these properties. Its easy to show that $\mathrm{Var}(aX) = a^2\mathrm{Var}(X)$ given that $\mathrm{Var}(X) = \mathrm{Cov}(X,X)$.

The Variance is called a *quadratic form*. A function, such as $\mathrm{Var}(X)$, is said to be a quadratic form if:

1. $\mathrm{Var}(aX) = a^2\mathrm{Var}(X)$, which we've shown to be true, and
2. $\mathrm{Var}(X+Y) - \mathrm{Var}(X) - \mathrm{Var}(Y)$ is itself bilinear. In the case of variances, the expression reduces to $2\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)$, which is bilinear.

The proofs for all of these properties fall out pretty readily from the expected value definitions of variance and covariance.

Comment: +1. Well explained!

Comment: More accurate to say variance is like a quadratic form, and covariance like a bilinear form. Suitably interpreted these are literally true statements. There is a natural way to turn quadratic forms into bilinear forms and vice versa ("polarization," as long as the characteristic is not two), and indeed that process swaps variance/covariance.

Comment: Indeed. Those terms escaped me at the time and frankly its beyond the scope. I have no interest in making a simple explanation into something convoluted just to show off my own knowledge.  Im teaching, not chanting with the choir.

Comment: Though your contribution is legitimate, it astonishes me how on this site, a legitimate question can go unanswered for over an hour, and when it finally does get answered competently, all these "know it alls" crawl out of the wood work to criticize the answer, not the question.  Just an FYI to @Financial_Physician, you will probably find a better culture and better answers on Yahoo Answers or Quora.

Comment: You could also add $Var(X-Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y)$

Comment: Unnecessary, I think.  (you forgot the covariance term, btw).  Its easily demonstrated with the properties provided. A subtraction is simply a -1 scalar and gets pulled out squared.  I could go on for hours listing properties, but it is all grossly beyond the scope of the question... and this isnt an encyclopedia or a text book. Thats why runway44 kind of annoyed me in the first place with his comment. Ive already gone well beyond the scope of the question.  By all means, post your own answers.